# PostgreSQL & JDBC "Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

i am currently working on a practice project to learn PostgreSQL. I would like to use the following method to get a customer number assignment. Customer numbers should be assigned consecutively when adding a new customer in the customer table (1,2,3,4,.....). The variable "anz" contains the number of customers in the table.

If a customer is deleted, his customer number becomes free again and can be assigned again.For example the customer number 3 becomes free again and the FOR- loop in getIndex() only runs until the 3. This number is then assigned. If all numbers are occupied, the next higher number is assigned. So if 1,2,3 are assigned, 4 is chosen.
The function checkEx() checks for each number (1,2,3,4,...) whether it is already present in the table.

I know I could realize this with Java but I would like to program it for practice in the database.
Unfortunately I always get the error "Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query". The functions contain several Select queries, which I replaced with PERFORM, but without success.

Sorry if this sounds a bit complicated, I hope it is understandable.
Can anyone help me?

```
public static int getKdNr() throws SQLException {
    

            String sql =
            "SELECT * FROM getIndex(); " +
        
            // getIndex()
            "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getIndex() RETURNS integer AS $BODY$ " +
                                    
                "DECLARE " +
    
                   "inx integer := 0; "                          +
                   "check integer := 0; " +
                   "anz integer := 0; " + 
                                         
                "BEGIN " + 
                
                "PERFORM 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM customer INTO anz'; " +
                
                            "FOR  i IN 1..anz LOOP "              +
                            //"check := checkVorh(i); "          + 

                              "PERFORM 'SELECT checkEx(i) INTO check'; " + 

                               "IF      check=1 THEN inx := i; "          +
                               "ELSE                 inx := anz+1; "            +
                               "END IF; "                         +          
                            "END LOOP; "                          +
        
                        "RETURN inx; "                            +
                "END; "                                           +
                    
            "$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; " +
            
            // checkEx(integer)
            "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkEx(integer) RETURNS integer AS $BODY$ " +
        
                "DECLARE " +
                
                    "ct integer; " +
                
                "BEGIN " +
                       
                    "PERFORM COUNT(1) INTO ct "      + 
                    "FROM customer "                            +                 
                    "WHERE unique_key = $1; "            +
                   
                    "RETURN ct; "             + 
                   
                "END; " +
            
            "$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; " ; 

        
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    return rs.getInt(1);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have now changed my program, but the if-statement does not work as it should.
But I don't understand why.

```
public static int getKdNr() throws SQLException {
    
String sql = "SELECT * FROM getIndex(); ";
                
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
rs.next();
return rs.getInt(1);
}


public static void createFunctions() throws SQLException {

stmt = conn.createStatement();

// checkEx(INTEGER)
    String sqlCheckEx = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkEx(INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $BODY$ " +

        "DECLARE " +
        
            "ct INTEGER; " +
        
        "BEGIN " +
               
            "PERFORM COUNT(1) INTO ct "      + 
            "FROM customer "                            +                 
            "WHERE unique_key = $1; "            +
           
            "RETURN ct; "             + 
           
        "END; " +
    
    "$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; " ; 
    
    stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCheckEx);
    }

    


// getIndex()
String sqlIndex = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getIndex() RETURNS INTEGER AS $BODY$ " +
    
                        
    "DECLARE " +

       "inx INTEGER   := 1; "                          +
       "check INTEGER := 0; " +
    
                     
    "BEGIN " + 
            
                "FOR  i IN 1.." + getAnzKd() + " LOOP "              +
                   "check := checkEx(i); "                           + 


                               "IF     check>0 THEN     inx := i; "                         +
                               "ELSE                  inx := " + (getAnzKd() +1) + "; "   +
                               "END IF; "                                               +     
                                       
                 "END LOOP; "                                              +
                        
            "RETURN inx; "                            +
            
    "END; " +
                                      
        
    
"$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; ";

stmt.executeUpdate(sqlIndex);

IO.println("\n\n--> Funktionen erstellt");}
```

Comment: There are several things very wrong here. The first thing being, every time you call the method, you're recreating two functions in the database.

Comment: @Kayaman That is true, of course. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately I still have this problem. I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your SQL to 3 separate query and call `executeQuery` for each of them.